# Doctrine 2.0 DQL concat parameter problem

Tags: doctrine, dql

Here is my code:

```
$query = $this->em->createQuery("select t.name,(select count(v) from Entity\Vacancy v where v.tags like '%t.name%') as weight from Entity\Tag t");
```

The problem:

> in quoted string t.name does not is replaced by value;

In sql format everything is working fine:

```
select tag.*,(select count(*) from vacancy where vacancy.tags like CONCAT('%',tag.name,'%')) as weight from tag
```

i try CONCAT (dql parameter) but parser throw errors, after LIKE parser wait only for a string.

**Have any way to do that?**